# Plot Shaded Area Between Two User-Defined Lines and Beneath Preexisting Data

Tags: matlab, plot, area

I am trying to add a grey shaded area between two user-defined vertical lines. I need this gray shaded area to appear beneath my already plotted data. I have tried using the fill and area functions, but haven't been able to successfully create a bounded area to appear underneath the Matlab plot. I need the shaded area plot to extend from the x-axis at vertical lines created at 5.5 and 19 and extend up to the y-axis at 900 (left y-axis) and at 1 (right y-axis). See here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qyzkuhw17yxn8p5/sample.png

Comment: Please provide an example and describe better the area that you need to fill (the current description is confusing).

Comment: So I plotted the four y variables first, then tried to use fill function like so: fill([5.5 5.5 19 19], [0 900 900 0],  [0.5 0.5 0.5], 'EdgeColor', 'none'). This resulted in the gray shaded area blocking the data as shown here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ltjbhzznfkyh0ds/shade.png

Comment: A. Donda and I have given two alternative solutions to that problem.

Comment: @user3052817: Did one of us help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    % Add shaded area to plot

    % Line 1
    hl1 = line(x1,y1,'Color','b'); 

    x = [5.5 5.5 19 19]; y = [0 900 900 0]; % define edges of shaded area

    % Locations for 5:30am and 19:00pm with the left y-axis ranging from 0-900 

    hl2=fill([x(1) x(2) x(3) x(4)], [y(1) y(2) y(3) y(4)],'Color','r','EdgeColor','none','LineStyle','none'); 

    hl1 = line(x1,y1,'Color','b'); % Replot line 1 over shaded area
    hold on; 

    % Continue adding more shaded areas using the fill function or add lines directly...
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the problem does not lie in generating the shaded area, but in making it appear *below* other elements of the plot even though it gets plotted *later*. You can achieve that by locating it "deeper", i.e. at a smaller z-value. Here is an example, building on the code by randomatlabuser:

```
x = linspace(0, 24, 100);
plot(x, 450 - 400 * cos(x / 12 * pi), 'k.-')
hold all

x = [5.5 5.5 19 19 5.5];
y = [0 900 900 0 0];
patch(x, y, -1 * ones(size(x)), [0.9 0.9 0.9], 'LineStyle', 'none')
```

`patch` is essentially the same as fill, but has a version that supports a third coordinate, the z-value.

Comment: See my update - you can obtain the same result by using the property `Children` of the current axes.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you want to do this:

```
h1 = plot((0:24), (0:700/24:700), '-b', 'LineWidth', 10); % some function
hold on
h2 = plot((0:24), 1.5 * (0:24) .^2, '-r', 'LineWidth', 10); % some other function

x = [5.5 5.5 19 19 5.5]; y = [0 900 900 0 0]; % define edges of area
h3 = fill(x, y, [0.9 0.9 0.9], 'LineStyle', 'none'); % fill area

set(gca, 'Children', [h1 h2 h3]) % h3 in the background, then h2 and finally h1 upfront
```

If not, you need to explain better what you are after.

Comment: I tried this; however, when I run it, I receive an error using set - "children may only be set to a permutation of itself". Perhaps this has to do with the fact that I plotted my data using the line function and have two separate axes functions to define the left and right y-axis properties (similar to what was done here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/using-multiple-x-and-y-axes.html;jsessionid=abb84386ac7d5f01a2208202d3f1?s_tid=doc_12b)?

Comment: You must select the axis where h3 belongs. Where did you plot h3? Can you report an example in your question?

Comment: I plotted h3 after I plotted all 4 y variables.

Comment: Please check `get(gca, 'Children')`: is `h3` a child?